Splitting lines on comma in pgfplotstable
I use pgfplotstable like this:
\pgfplotstableset{
every even row/.style={ before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
every head row/.style={
  before row={\hline \rowcolor[gray]{0.7}},
  after row=\hline
},
assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
every last row/.style={ after row=\hline},
col sep=comma,
verb string type,
text indicator="
}

Note: I use verb string type because my part numbers contains # sometimes and with string type it doesn't work.
And I render the data with this:
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{bom.csv}

bom.csv contains
"Reference","Value","Qty","MPN","Manufacturer"
"C1,C22","100n","2","GCD21BR71H104KA01L","Murata"
"C2,C11,C12","4u7","3","GRM21BR61H475KE51L","Murata"
"C3,C9,C10","1u","3","GCM21BR71H105KA03L","Murata"
"C4,C13,C14,C15,C16","22n","5","CC0805JRX7R9BB223","Yageo"
"R1","10m","1","ERJ-6CWFR011V","Panasonic Electronic Components"


It generates the following result:

I'd like to limit the width of the table to \linewidth as we can see it's wider in the image and I'd like the first column, "Reference", to wrap on comma if needed and last column to wrap anywhere if needed (whitespace and hyphenation). If latex cannot automatically find the best column width, defining column width to something like 20%,10%,10%,30%,30% is fine.
I use pandoc and lualatex, and the complete generated file looks like this:
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math} % this also loads fontspec
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifPDFTeX\else
  % xetex/luatex font selection
  \setmathfont[]{Asana Math}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{inter}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{float}
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{H}
\makeatother
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Test BOM},
  pdfauthor={Test},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}

\title{Test BOM}
\author{Test}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\pagebreak

\pgfplotstableset{
column type/.add={|}{},
every last column/.style={column type=|c|},
every even row/.style={ before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
every head row/.style={
  before row={\hline \rowcolor[gray]{0.7}},
  after row=\hline
},
assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
every last row/.style={ after row=\hline},
col sep=comma,
string type,
text indicator="
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{bom.csv}

\end{document}



Welcome to tex.sx.
